# ASP .Net Core 2 Self Contained Deployment giving 502.5 Error in IIS under different App Pool Identity Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, full-trust

I have an ASP .Net Core 2 Web Api application targeting netcoreapp2.1 and deploying as self-contained (produces an exe) to IIS.

On this server the app will work with the existing App Pool configured to run under a specific AD account.

When we change it to use a different account which appears to have the same permissions to the folders as the first account, the app won't start and gives a 502.5 error.

[image]

Here's the really weird part. If we run another site pointed to the same application folder but under the first AD account it works **and THEN** run the site with the seconds AD account, it will now work perfectly fine.

Another bit of info, the physical location of the application files is on a network share. When we move the physical files to the IIS server (to run it locally) it will work but due to our enterprise setup, this isn't an option in production. So it seems it might be related to some sort of permission/policy for starting the exe from a network share using UNC file path.

**UPDATE**
The files are shared from a NAS not a Windows Server share. Also, I have determined that for the user this fails for the application reports that it runs in the Internet zone whereas the other user it runs in the Intranet zone.

How are these zones determined?

Below is the stdout logs when it fails.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.<BindAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<StartAsync>d__22`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.<StartAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Possible this is related to SMBv1. Looking into that.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?
I get a similar error after a self-contained deployment of an asp.net core 2.1 application to an IIS.

Comment: @dybzon turns out there is some low level issue where the account that the host is running under has to have permissions at all levels of the network share. Even though the user can read the files in the shared folder, it would fail unless that user has permissions at all folder levels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our issue, it turns out that the account under which the site is running must have read permissions at every directory level of the NAS file share path. Once this was done, the server started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to publish the website/project as a self-contained application. In order to publish it as a self-contained application, please add this to the csproj folder.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64;win7-x86;ubuntu.16.04-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<SuppressDockerTargets>True</SuppressDockerTargets>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Actually the self contained is part of the problem. It works as a framework dependent because the executable isn't being executed over a network share like a SC deployment.

Comment: Believe it has to do with some sort of policy affecting the security of the dotnet exe that gets executed from a network share.